# Azure Webjob: will it retry if it doesn't get a response within a certain timeframe?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

We have an Azure Webjob running on one of our websites that is supposed to run once a day, during the night. This generally processes some data, updates a few records ... It's a process that runs for a few minutes and in the end simply prints "OK".

The Webjob is set to run at 10 PM. 
Now, we notice in our logging, that it does indeed run at 10PM, and then runs again at 10:01PM and 10:02PM and 10:03PM. It runs four times.

What I suppose is happening is that the job is taking some time to process (it takes about three minutes on our production environment) and the Azure Webjob keeps triggering it once every minute until it receives a response.

Can someone confirm or deny this? I've tried reading the documentation and googling for this specific problem, but couldn't find much information about it, other than that it might show this behavior if an exception is thrown (which is definitely not the case).

Can this behavior be configured in some way?